# Approach to Adding rows to table in React screen

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning React and Redux and I have a doubt:

I need to add rows to an existing table.

For this, I save data used in all rows in an array in prop and then render this array again every time a row is added.

like adding 100th row in an existing table of 99 rows needs all 99 rows to be rendered again.

Isn't this costly?

or is it better than traditional way using jquery (maybe because of virtual dom)

What else could be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

React is smart, if you used the key props in your map, it will render only the element that has changed. Because it will make a diff from the previous list.

But be careful if you use the index and not a unique id , when the number of element is huge, rendering can become unreliable : https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

React has a **shouldComponentUpdate** life cycle where you can check should or not rerender component again when you add a new row.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualDOM pretty much takes care of this!

Pulled from the Code Academy page on Virtual DOM:

> How it helps
>
> When you render a JSX element, every single virtual DOM object gets updated.
>
> This sounds incredibly inefficient, but the cost is insignificant because the virtual DOM can update so quickly.
>
> Once the virtual DOM has updated, then React compares the virtual DOM with a virtual DOM snapshot that was taken right before the update.
>
> By comparing the new virtual DOM with a pre-update version, React figures out exactly which virtual DOM objects have changed. This process is called "diffing."
>
> Once React knows which virtual DOM objects have changed, then React updates those objects, and only those objects, on the real DOM. In our example from earlier, React would be smart enough to rebuild your one checked-off list-item, and leave the rest of your list alone.
>
> This makes a big difference! React can update only the necessary parts of the DOM. React's reputation for performance comes largely from this innovation.

As a side note, make sure to use the key element (if you don't have a unique ID in the table, you can use array index). When doing a huge table, it might also be beneficial to look into options such as pagination to help with performance.